# I can not run my tophat function

Tags: python, linux

I am doing one transcriptome assembly using the tophat command.
In one folder i have my reference genome in GTF in this same folder I have my bowtie index files.
In other folder i have my two split fasta files of my transcriptome. I put the command tophat but appears that could not find the bowtie indexes files. I am using `tophat 1.41` and the six bowtie files are in `.ebwt`.

I am typing the next command

```
tophat -o myfolder --mate-inner-dist 50 --mate-std-dev 20 -p 5 
/file/file1/myfolder/myfolder2/referencegenome.gtf /file/file1/myfolder/myfolder2 
/file/file1/myfolder/transcriptome_1.fastq /file/file1/myfolder/transcriptome_1.fastq
```

In my folder2 I have my ebwt files. I created them with bowtie build command and I downloaded my reference genome from JGI in .gff, i transformed later to .gtf.

Any suggestions on what am I doing wrong? 
What the tophat command can not find these files even if they are in `myfolder2`.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error?

Answer (score 0):

Some comments
1. Tophat do a mapping of your fastq reads to a reference genome or transcriptome. Not an assembly.

2. If you have a reference genome such as referencegenome.fa, then you need to build an index with it using bowtie. In this case it is recommended to name that index with the same prefix that your genome fasta file, that is, referencegenome.

Then, you will see referencegenome.ebwt files along with your referencegenome.fa and the referencegenome.gtf files all together in the same directory

But with TopHat you need invoke the reference and indexed genome by calling it as referencegenome (use only the prefix of the indexed files. Don't need to add gtf, ebwt or the fa endings).

You did it by calling the gtf file, so the indexed files were not found. Neither the reference genome, so TopHat could not build up the index for you

I also suggest you to visit seqanwers.com and biostars.org, two specialized forums dedicated to NGS
And Gregor is right. This has nothing to do with R